# Sharepoint 2013 authentication node js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, sharepoint

is there any way authenticate by node js ? i want to use node web api using sharepoint 2013 auth by username and password.after user login i will reach sharepoint lists for crud operations. i used node-sp-auth but these codes doesnt work for me. still i am getting 401 error code.

```
spauth
.getAuth('http://domain', {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'pass1',
    host: 'domain'
})
.then(data => {
    let headers = data.headers;
    headers['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
    let requestOpts = data.options;
    requestOpts.json = true;
    requestOpts.headers = headers;
    requestOpts.url = "http://domain/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('cari')/Items?";
    request.get(requestOpts).then(response => {
        console.log(response.d.Title);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the sp-request to achieve it.

```
import * as sprequest from 'sp-request';

var context = {
    siteUrl: "http://domain",
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    domain: "domain"
};

var spr = sprequest.create(context);

var restUrl = context.siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('cari')/items";

spr.get(restUrl).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(err =>{
    console.log('Ohhh, something went wrong...');
});
```

More information is here: [sp-request - simplified SharePoint HTTP client](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request)